# Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку - не перекидывало на другую ссылку?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, form, button

Сделал валидацию для кнопки через jquery-vaildate. По макету - нужно сделать так, чтобы после нажатии на кнопку, которая отправляет эту форму - закрывался этот popup и открывался следующий с уведомлением о том, что форма отправлена. Подскажите, как это сделать? Все скрины прикрепил ниже. HTML формы:

```
<form action="login" class="modal__form">
                                    <input type="text" name="firstName" class="modal__item" required placeholder="Имя">
                                    <input type="email" name="mail" class="modal__item"required  placeholder="E-mail">
                                    <input type="tel" name="phoneNumber" class="modal__item" required placeholder="Телефон">
                                    <button type="submit" class="modal__btn" id="modal__btn">
                                            Заказать звонок
                                    </button>
</form>
```

Код валидации:

```
$('.modal__form').validate({
        rules: {
            firstName : {
                required : true,
                regex : "[A-Za-zА-Яа-я]{1,32}"
            },
            phoneNumber : {
                required : true,
                digits: true,
                minlength : 7,
                maxlength : 15,
                regex: "[0-9]+"
            },
            mail : {
                required : true
            }
        },
        messages : {
            firstName : 'Введите имя правильно!',
            phoneNumber : 'Введите номер правильно!',
            mail : 'Введите почту правильно!'
        }
    })
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а код где?) чего куда? у вас скорее всего `button:type=submit`, а форма с экшеном, вот и url меняется. `e.preventDefault()` на вскидку

Comment: Я добавил HTML формы, посмотрите, пожалуйста)

Comment: Что за сайт, с какой страницы перекидывает и дайте jQuery и js код

Comment: @BuratinoApps, на главной есть кнопка, которую нажимаешь и открывается popup окно. В этом popup - форма с кнопкой отправки. После нажатия на кнопку - перекидывается на страницу, ссылку которую я показал на скрине. Добавил код валидации в вопрос. Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: Если вам нужно закрыть один попап и открыть другой без перезагрузки страницы при етом отправить данные формы то нужен аякс запрос. Логика такая проверяем валидность формы, если все нормально то отправляэм аякс запрос, если запрос успешен то закрываем попап с формой и открываем попап с сообщением что данные отправлены.

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk, сейчас буду пробовать. Спасибо